# Enterprise Architect: Can you generate a report from separate packages?

Tags: enterprise-architect

Is there a way to combine multiple packages into one (html) report? I don't want to generate a report from the parent package because it contains a lot of information not related to the desired report. I'm looking for an answer that does not require copy/pasting the separate packages into a new parent package, mainly because that forces me to update the links between the various diagrams and is quite time consuming.

Comment: Reading through my answer, I realize I may have misinterpreted your question. So just to clarify: have you tried (and dismissed) setting up «model document»s?

Comment: @Uffe, this looks like what I was looking for. Why didn't you post this as an answer? I'm working on setting this up now.

Comment: @Uffe, add it to your answer or add another answer and I will mark it as the answer. Until then, since this is exactly what I was looking for, I will add it myself and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @Uffe, there actually is an elegant solution in EA. You can create a documentation diagram and add model document or master document elements to it. To these elements you can then add packages from anywhere in the model, and then publish this combination in any of the supported formats. More details [here](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.2/reporting/createadocumentobject.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can't combine the output of several HTML (or document) reports into one. You can do the opposite: you can exclude certain packages from generation.

Simply select each (child) package you wish to exclude, right-click and select Documentation -- Generated Report Options... This allows you to choose whether the package is included in the report. This option is recursive, so the package and all its child packages are excluded.

The other option is to write a script which traverses a package structure and selectively generates documentation for it using the DocumentGenerator class.

Comment: I didn't know about that, thanks. It's actually quite impractical, though, given a large enterprise model from which you want to generate different reports for different situations, since it's a static and not report-specific configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to create a report from the parent package, and you don't want to copy/paste, so try this: create a new package, drag the packages that you wish to report on into the new package, create the report on the new package, drag the packages back where they came from, and delete the new package.